# Default values with @ProjectedPayload / ProjectingJackson2HttpMessageConverter

Tags: java, spring-data, kotlin, jsonpath

I am using `@ProjectedPayload` on an interface to bind a JSON request body to a proxied instance of my interface.
My interface is as follows (in Kotlin, the `val` just translates to a Java getter):

```java
@ProjectedPayload
interface ImportServer {

    val id: UUID?
    val name: String?

}
```

Now, the `id` here is completely optional, but there is no way for me to specify that, at least as far as I can tell. If I try to access the `id` property without it being present in the request body I will receive an exception from JsonPath: `com.jayway.jsonpath.PathNotFoundException: No results for path: $['id']`. If I could configure JsonPath I could use `Option.DEFAULT_PATH_LEAF_TO_NULL` and I'd get `null` for elements that are not present. But there is no way for me to get at the JsonPath configuration, it happens locked away inside `JsonProjectingMethodInterceptorFactory`.

Is there a way for me to specify a default here? Or is there a way for me to detect if the `id` is present without accessing the `id` property in the first place?

Comment: Why do you need `id`? If you handle 'POST /items' request - then you **insert** new `@RequestBody Item item` without `id` to the DB. If you handle, for example, 'PUT /items/{id}' request - then you **update** existing item that is retrieved from DB with help of `@PathVariable("id") Item storedItem` annotation...

Comment: Yes, that is true for the `id`, I admit my example was bad in that sense. But say that specifying the name is optional, defaulting to an autogenerated name or you can optionally specify an owner, whatever it may be.

Comment: Payload (request body) should be immutable IMO. I think that  autogenerated values are not part of input data...

Comment: Yes, it is immutable.
But user of the API can choose not to specify a name. Is that not reasonable?

Comment: reasonable, but in this case you are in charge what to do next - you analyze the input data and make a decision (but not the data do it for you). IMO...

Comment: So you think the API user should always have to explicitly state all fields in the input data and then if they do not want a specific field use `null`?

Comment: I think if you get `null` in the input data (at the back-end) then you have to process it, not the data.

Comment: I am not sure I follow you. I am trying to design the interface to use as my `@RequestBody`. If I put the `name` in that interface, the user of the API _must_ specify that field in the body, or accessing `name` in the controller method will throw an exception. I am trying to find a way to check whether or not `name` was specified, without just catching that exception. Using the exception seems like a "wrong" way to do it to me. Maybe that's where I am wrong though.

Comment: Maybe I didn't correct understand you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a bug and has been fixed with [DATACMNS-1145](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATACMNS-1145). Will be released with Ingalls SR7 and transitively with Boot 1.5.7.